# Can not pass special character to subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this command which I can get the external IP address returned from Unix shell, so I can use it in my server:

```
ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p'
```

on my mac, terminal returns:

> 192.168.1.3

How do I get this outputted in the python script? I have tried:

```
import subprocess

command = ['ifconfig', '|', 'sed', '-En', 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
text = p.stdout.read()
retcode = p.wait()
```

and I got error says

> ifconfig: interface | does not exist

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're running nothing but an `ifconfig` command here, with `|` as its first parameter and `sed` as its second...  The ability to run multiple commands piped together is a feature of the shell; you'd need to add `shell=True` to make this work.  You'll also need to use a raw string for that final parameter, so that the backslashes don't get interpreted by Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell command is invoking two commands, the output of `ifconfig` is used as input to `sed`. You could emulate this using subprocess but the `sed` call is just doing some text manipulation, so a cleaner approach would just be to use Python for that step. For example:

```
import re
import subprocess

pattern = r'inet (?:addr:)?(?!127\.0\.0\.1)((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)'

p = subprocess.Popen(['ifconfig'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
text = re.search(pattern, p.stdout.read()).group(1)
retcode = p.wait()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works! P.s. `p.stdout.read()` should be `p.stdout.read().decode()` otherwise the program won't recongize the pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p'
```

you are trying to envoke 2 shell commands, `ifconfig` and `sed`, which is okay. but, these are shell commands and the shell keyword argument must be set to true when calling the `subprocess.Poen`.

use the communictae method, it better to use here. and dispatch the command as a string not list.

```
import subprocess

command = ' '.join(['ifconfig', '|', 'sed', '-En', 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p'])
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdoutdata, stderrdata = p.communicate()  #this is blocking
for line in stdoutdata:
    #do some thing with line
```

`Popen.communicate(input=None)`

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and
> stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.
> The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child
> process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.